# How to remove dist-packages from file… navigation in Pycharm?

Tags: navigation, ide, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm as my main IDE but when using the `Navigate > File…` to quick jump to a file I got lot of noise from python packages (*e.g.* `dist-package`):

[image: How to remove dist-packages from file… nagivation in Pycharm?]

#### Project pane (external libraries)

[image: project pane (external libraries)]

Tihs become super annoying when working on purely JS project where I have no need for Python.

#### Question

Is there a way to remove this directory from the list of suggestion look up? I know we can filter by extension, not want I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Project Structure` dialog you can mark specific path as excluded and it should be skipped then. Here is a [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html) or [another](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/excluding-files-from-projects.html) to the official doc.

Comment: you can't exclude this part with this method, I will update my question to be more precise